# Kendu UI Paragraph styling

Tags: kendo-ui, paragraph

I am using Kendo UI Editor and would like to change the default `margin-bottom:1em` which is added by inline style affecting the `<P>` tag.

I would like it to default as `.5em` instead.

Right now I am using the defaultTool "insertParagrah" to remove the Paragraphs but I would rather affect the  which gets added to the  in the Kendo iframe.

```
var defaultTools = kendo.ui.Editor.defaultTools;
        defaultTools["insertParagraph"].options.shift = true;

        $( "#message" ).kendoEditor(
            {
                messages: {
                    fontSizeInherit: ""
                },
                tools: [
                    {
                        name: "fontSize",
                        items: [
                                { text: "8px", value: "8px" },
                                { text: "10px", value: "10px" },
                                { text: "12px", value: "12px" },
                                { text: "14px", value: "14px" },
                                { text: "16px", value: "16px" }]

                    },
                    "foreColor", "bold", "italic", "underline", "strikethrough", "justifyLeft", "justifyCenter", "justifyRight", "insertOrderedList", "insertUnorderedList",
                    "indent", "outdent"
                ]
            }
            );
```

Comment: .k-editable-area{margin-bottom:0.53m;}

Comment: Or do you mean to the paragraphs within the editor?

Comment: Could you please provide screenshot or code snippet, where this style is defined?

Comment: added the code but cannot add an image because this is the first time I have ever posted to StackOverflow.